# Mysql Full outer join two subqueries

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

I know mysql does not support full outer join, and doing this you have to basically left join/right join and do union. I have two tables one contains all possible keys with labels for them for the accounts,  other contains values for the keys for each client in the account. I want to get all keys for the account and if it has value record value as well and I want to filter by the type.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account_meta` (
  `account_meta_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `rank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_meta_id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `key` (`key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;


INSERT INTO `account_meta` (`account_meta_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `rank`, `account_id`) VALUES(1, 'contact', 'Facebook', '', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `account_meta` (`account_meta_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `rank`, `account_id`) VALUES(2, 'contact', 'Instagram', '', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO `account_meta` (`account_meta_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `rank`, `account_id`) VALUES(3, 'contact', 'Phone', '', 3, 1);
INSERT INTO `account_meta` (`account_meta_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `rank`, `account_id`) VALUES(4, 'contact', 'Email', '', 4, 1);
INSERT INTO `account_meta` (`account_meta_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `rank`, `account_id`) VALUES(5, 'contact', 'WeChat', '', 5, 1);
INSERT INTO `account_meta` (`account_meta_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `rank`, `account_id`) VALUES(6, 'stage', 'Sky', '', 6, 1);
INSERT INTO `account_meta` (`account_meta_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `rank`, `account_id`) VALUES(7, 'stage', 'Why', '', 7, 1);
INSERT INTO `account_meta` (`account_meta_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `rank`, `account_id`) VALUES(8, 'stage', 'My', '', 8, 1);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_contact` (
  `client_contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_meta_id` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_contact_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `key` (`account_meta_id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

INSERT INTO `client_contact` (`client_contact_id`, `client_id`, `account_id`, `account_meta_id`, `value`) VALUES(2, 11, 1, 1, 'https://www.yahoo.com');
INSERT INTO `client_contact` (`client_contact_id`, `client_id`, `account_id`, `account_meta_id`, `value`) VALUES(3, 11, 1, 2, 'Serua');
INSERT INTO `client_contact` (`client_contact_id`, `client_id`, `account_id`, `account_meta_id`, `value`) VALUES(4, 11, 1, 3, 'abs');
INSERT INTO `client_contact` (`client_contact_id`, `client_id`, `account_id`, `account_meta_id`, `value`) VALUES(6, 11, 1, 5, 'oragnas');
INSERT INTO `client_contact` (`client_contact_id`, `client_id`, `account_id`, `account_meta_id`, `value`) VALUES(7, 12, 1, 5, 'oragnas');
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jHzANXZDjykpSWMcsX5a5f/5

Basically I want first query result to be full outer join to the second query result in mysql (5.7). The 3rd query is my attempt to do so, but what ever I do, I can not get it work to return. I have tried doing cross join, but get duplicate record with duplicate account_meta_id, first record has value other one null. I try doing this by adding case/when if the account_meta_id are the same or not

Comment: Edit your question and show the queries that you are talking about.  What keys are the keys for the `join`, for instance?

Comment: account_meta_id,account_id are the key which join both tables to each other

Answer (score 0):

The left join/right join is definitely not the best way to emulate a full join (it is both too expensive and it incurs overhead for removing duplicated results that is just silly).

One method is to construct all the keys and then use only `left join`:

```
with am as (
      select *
      from `account_meta`
      where account_id = 1 and `type` = 'contact'
     ),
     cc as (
      select *
      from `client_contact`
      where account_id = 1 and client_id = 11
     )
select am.*, cc.*
from ((select <key>  -- whatever the key is for the join
       from am
      ) union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select <key>
       from cc
      )
     ) k left join
     cc
     on cc.<key> = k.<key> left join
     am
     on am.<key> = k.<key>;
```

Comment: Can not use with, the data in mysql 5.7